# .htaccess convert url from route parameter to query string with blank parameter value

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess

I have .htaccess  issue where url is in route parameter but I want's to convert it on query string format.

Current path is :
`http://localhost:4200/act/sso/app/2040/token/7d2f-4ddd-924f-3fd36572/address/chd/city/chd/state/chd`

I want's to convert it on : `http://localhost:4200/act/sso?app=2040&token=7d2f-4ddd-924f-3fd36572&address=chd&city=chd&state=chd`

I have write below .htaccess rule.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^act/sso/app/32/token/([^/]*)/address/([^/]*)/city/([^/]*)/state/([^/]*)

RewriteRule ^act/sso/app/32/token/([^/]*)/address/([^/]*)/city/([^/]*)/state/([^/]*) act/sso?appID=32&mfaToken=$1&address=$2&city=$3&state=$4 [R=301,L]
```

My problem is when we are getting optional parameter value, my route rule is not matching.

See in below example.

```
http://localhost:4200/act/sso/app/2040/token/7d2f-4ddd-924f-3fd36572/address//city//state/chd

http://localhost:4200/act/sso/app/2040/token/7d2f-4ddd-924f-3fd36572/address/chd/city//state/chd

http://localhost:4200/act/sso/app/2040/token/7d2f-4ddd-924f-3fd36572/address/chd/city/chd/state/
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/act/sso/app/([0-9]+)/token/([^/]*)/address/([^/]*)/city/([^/]*)/state/([^/]*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /act/sso?app=%1&token=%2&address=%3&city=%4=state=%5 [L,NE,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Still not maintaining proper url. for blank value, apache converting double slash to single slash like act/sso/app/20/token/7d2f572/address/city/state/chd. Can we set null value for blank value? then it will be proper and we can replace. like /act/sso/app/20/token/7d2f572/address/null/city/null/state/chd